# Amida together with the chazzan

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, kedusha-prayer, chazarat-hashatz

If one came late to davening and he can not make tefila betzibur as he won’t have time to get up the amida with th congregation, he should say the amida together with the chazzan ([SA OC 109:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.109.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Does the individual recite the kedusha and the birkhat kohanim together with the chazzan as well?

Answer (score 8):

R Eli Mansour [brings](https://itorah.com/power-search-results/6/1334) the Shulchan Aruch ([OC 109:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.109.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that

> if a person comes late to the synagogue and misses the congregation's
> silent Amidah, he can still earn the merit of praying with the
> congregation by reciting the Amidah word for word with the Chazan.
> When he and the Chazan complete the Beracha of "Mechayei Ha'meitim,"
> **he recites Kedusha together with the Chazan**.  He then continues "Ata
> Kadosh" with the Chazan, and bows with the Chazan at the recitation of
> "Modim."
>
> After the Beracha of "Ha'tov Shimcha U'le'cha Na'eh
> Le'hodot," **he should stop and listen to Birkat Kohanim.  He may also
> answer "Amen" to the Beracha preceding Birkat Kohanim and after each
> of the three verses of Birkat Kohanim** (after "Ve'yishmirecha,"
> "Vi'chuneka" and "Shalom").  He should not, however, answer "Baruch Hu
> U'varuch Shemo" during Birkat Kohanim.

Comment: what about the Ashkenazi custom where the chazzan is the one reciting the birkhat kohanim during the week - what would be the Halacha there, can he recite it with the chazzan? @mbloch

Comment: @Draizy It's not just Ashkenzi. It's everyone's practice for when full Birkat Kohanim doesn't happen for whatever reason on any day

Comment: Correct you are. I also don’t understand the MB there about why one has to say ha-kel hakadosh and shomei tefilah along with the chazzan because of the Amen’s; do those amens have a different status?